# Understanding the concept of measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am currently reading Lebesgue Integration on the Euclidean Space by Frank Jones , in my course of self study I came upon this doubt . 
The book defines the measure of an open set with the following definition , 
 If $G\subset R^{n}$ is an open set and G is not an empty set , we define

$\lambda(G)$ = sup{$\lambda(P)| P\subset G$ , where P is a special polygon}

My doubt is whether the following proof of mine of a property that stems from the following definition is complete

To prove if $G_1 \subset G_2 $ then $\lambda(G_1) \leq \lambda(G_2) $

MY attempt

Let A = {$\lambda (P) | P \subset G_1 $ }
    B = {$\lambda(P)| P|\subset G_2 $ }

Now since $G_1 \subset G_2 $  we can say that $ A \subset B $ . 
Thus $sup(A) \leq sup(B)$

I ask this because the book mention the following lines extra in the proof for which I do not see any need 
Since $\lambda(G_2)$ is the least upper bound of the set B , it is an upper bound ofr the same set . There fore $\lambda(G_2)$  is also an upper bound for the smaller set A. As $\lambda(G_1)$ is the least upper bound of this set, we get $\lambda(G_1) \subset \lambda(G_2) $.

In a sense my question boils down to , the fact that I fail to understand why the explanation about the upper bounds supplied in the book is needed at all !

Comment: It seems that the book is merely clarifying the fact that $A\subset B\implies \sup A\leq \sup B$ in case there are readers who don't see that as obvious.

Answer (score 0):

He's just saying the following in a convoluted way:

\begin{align}
P\subset G_1 &\implies P \subset G_2 \\
&\implies \lambda (P) \leq \lambda (G_2) &&\text{definition of sup} \\\\
\therefore P \text{ arbitrary}&\implies \lambda(G_1) \leq \lambda(G_2) 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

To conclude the proof, you need

> **Lemma**: if $X \subseteq Y$ then $\mathrm{sup}(X) \leq \mathrm{sup}(Y)$

You are taking this as a given and using it without comment, and that's probably a fine thing to do.

The author however, decided that more explanation is needed, and repeated what is basically the main step in the proof of this lemma.